# How do I make a 25s delay to delete an item after it has been created?

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I make a 25s delay to delete an item after it has been created?

CustomControl.MessageSucceed() I want it to last 25 seconds and then it was deleted.

enter code here

```
    public StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
    public void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stackPanel.Children.Add(new CustomControl.MessageSucceed());

        if (!RemovingGrid.Children.Contains(stackPanel))
        {
            stackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            stackPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            RemovingGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
        }
        Task.Delay(25000).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make `OkButton_Click` `async` and simply `await` `Task.Delay`:

```
public StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
public async void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var @object = new CustomControl.MessageSucceed();
    stackPanel.Children.Add(@object);

    if (!RemovingGrid.Children.Contains(stackPanel))
    {
        stackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        stackPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        RemovingGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
    }
    await Task.Delay(25000);
    stackPanel.Children.Remove(@object);
}
```

Comment: it is usually a good practice for any `async void` function to use try/catch, otherwise there is a risk that exceptions are lost and not noticed.